# Area of a Section of the Unit Sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

I am currently studying for the GRE. I came across the following question, and I can't seem to get the correct answer. The question reads:

> Compute the area of a unit sphere contained between the meridians $\phi =30^{\circ}$ and $\phi = 60^{\circ}$ and parallels $\theta =45^{\circ}$ and $\theta =60^{\circ}$.

First, I recalled that the area element of the unit sphere is: $dA=\sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta$. From there, I made the following computations:

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\sin(\phi)d\phi d\theta  = \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2})d\theta = \frac{\pi}{12}(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2})$$

However, the correct answer is: $\frac{\pi}{12}(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})$. Any guidance on this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Technically there are two patches since the great circles for $\theta$ come around the back. Maybe that's where the factor of two comes in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since here $\theta$ denotes the [latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#The_graticule_on_the_sphere) ($\theta=0^{\circ}$ is the equator), the element of area is $dA=\cos(\theta)d\phi d\theta$, and therefore the required area is
$$\int_{\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{\phi=\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\cos(\theta)d\phi d\theta=\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})}{12}.$$