# Compute the area of a unit sphere contained between the meridians φ = 30◦ and φ = 60◦ and parallels θ = 45◦ and θ = 60◦

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Compute the area of a unit sphere contained between the meridians φ = 30◦ and φ = 60◦ and parallels θ = 45◦ and θ = 60◦

So I have the triple integral set up, is this correct?

$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_0^1  d \rho d \phi d \theta$$

But this doesn't give the correct answer, where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Three issues: (a) a triple integral might be suitable for a volume rather than an area and (b) you seem to be looking a rectangle (or perhaps a cuboid) but parallels are not in fact straight lines and for this area the parallel nearer the pole is shorter than the parallel closer to the equator; and (c) the area is sloping (and a changing slope) rather than vertical as the sphere is round

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3720295/area-of-a-section-of-the-unit-sphere/